# How to stop the link from redirecting in Kentico CMS when the user log in as admin/CMS editor?

Tags: kentico

Is it possible / how to stop the link from redirecting in Kentico CMS when the user log in as admin/CMS editor?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the logging to CMS (from /CMSPages/logon.aspx) you can create a custom login page and redirect user where you want.

Use the Logon Form web part to achive this. In the properties of that web part you can setup Default target URL, which leads users to approporiate page You want

Comment: Thanks for your response.